# Python. trigger .exe(which works as drag and drop with excel file) while in cmd

Tags: python, cmd, path, exe

I have an application that works when I drag an excel file on top on the `.exe`

Now I want to trigger that application using `python(3.8)`, the ways I tried:

```
def mycmd():

     os.system('cmd /c "\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myexe.exe" \\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myexcel.xlsx')

mycmd()
```

This way it ignored `.xlsx` and runs only `exe.` I tried to play with quotation marks, didn't help, either only `.exe` boots or I get 'The network name cannot be found.'

Both of the files are stored in a shared network

`os.listdir(path)` shows both of the files I need.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Open Task Manager. In Details, add command line column. Open the file with drag-and-drop as usual, check what command gets executed (new column!) and use it

Comment: @h4z3, unfortunately, this didn't help, column shows:
"\\Folder\F1\F2\F3\F4\F5\F6\F7\my.exe" "\\Folder\F1\F2\F3\F4\F5\F6\F7\excel.exe"
it says: The system cannot find the path specified, when i add "\" to the path to look like this:

'cmd /c "\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myexe.exe" "\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myexcel.xlsx"')

i get: The network name cannot be found.

Comment: Why are you trying to launch it with `cmd /c` and not the command directly?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Sorry, i'm pretty new to python

Comment: It's not about python, it's about you put in `os.system`. You do `cmd /c file.exe file.xlsx` - why the `cmd /c`?

Comment: Because I didn't think of any other way to trigger an .exe considering the way it works, only through cmd

Comment: But os.system already uses commands. So you put whatever you would have put in cmd

Comment: Hey you led me on the right track, thanks. I made it work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution to my case.

```
path = "\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myexe.exe"
path_input = "\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\myfile.xlsx"

def myprocess():

       os.chdir("\\\\Folder\\F2\\F3\\F4\\F5\\F6\\F7\\F8\\") # i made this because of output of .exe
       subprocess.call([f'{path}', f'{path_input}'])

myprocess()
```

Comment: For paths please consider using literal string: r'\\folder\F2\....'